# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pipe')

Tags: angular, unit-testing

**Service**

```
export interface ITransferRequest {
    serviceName:string;
    amount:number
}

@Injectable()
export class TransferService
{
    transferMoneyUrl = 'https://localhost:44321/api/TransferService';

    constructor(private http:HttpClient){}

    doTransfer(transferRequest: ITransferRequest): Observable<TransferResult> {
        return this.http.post<TransferResult>(this.transferMoneyUrl, transferRequest).pipe();
      }
}
```

**Test Code**

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {

  let transferService: TransferService,
  mockHttp: any;

  beforeEach(async () => {

    mockHttp = jasmine.createSpyObj('mockHttp',['get', 'post']);
    transferService = new TransferService(mockHttp);

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();

  });

  it('should do transfer', done => {
    
    const transferRequest: ITransferRequest = { serviceName: "A", amount: 1000 };

    mockHttp.get.and.returnValue(of(<TransferResult>{ result : 600 }));

    transferService.doTransfer(<ITransferRequest>transferRequest)
      .subscribe((x: TransferResult) => {   
        expect(x.result).toBe(600);
        done();
      });
   
  });
```

**ERROR**

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pipe')
    at TransferService.doTransfer (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/services/transfer.service.ts:32:86)
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/app.component.spec.ts:35:21)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:372:1)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-testing.js:287:1)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:371:1)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:134:1)
    at runInTestZone (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-testing.js:564:1)
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-testing.js:580:1)
    at <Jasmine>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the TestBed configuration is totally useless in your sample. Just delete it.

Your bug is because you are providing a mock return value for `get` but your method under test calls `post`. Because the default return value for spied methods is `undefined` it blows up on the `.pipe()` with that error.

Comment: I got blind I guess, thanks you saved me hours :)